# Where should I put my Javascript code in a ColdFusion model glue view?

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, model-glue

Let's say I have a ColdFusion Model Glue view called `login.cfm`. In it, I have a form:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="#event.linkTo("user.login")#" method="POST">
    E-mail: <input id="emailField" type="text" name="email">
    Password: <input id="passwordField" type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Now I want to add in some Javascript validation for when the user clicks the Login button. Something like this in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
            // check that emailField is not empty and is a valid e-mail
            // check that passwordField is not empty
            // if validation fails, add in DOM elements to show error messages
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where should I be adding this Javascript code? Do I stick it directly into the `login.cfm` view? Or is there a better way of handling this? Preferably, I'd like to stick my Javascript code from all my views to the bottom of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a quite a few different strategies for this. The easiest is it put your view-specific script in a single .js file and include it through a `<script src="path"></script>` tag just before closing the `<body>` tag.

You can also look at libraries such as require.js that allow you to asynchronously load script files and their dependencies.

Comment: Wouldn't this break if the login form doesn't exist though?

Comment: If the login form doesn't exist, the jQuery example you've got there will just do nothing. (If necessary, you can do an `if ($('#loginForm').length > 0)` check to make sure of this.)

Comment: +1 to Peter.  One of the nice things about jQuery is, if it doesn't find the specified element, it just shrugs and goes on about its business.  Doesn't throw an error.

Comment: I'd also add that you can absolutely include a single .js file from the bottom of your view/cfm file, rather than putting it in a layout file.  If I have JS that affects a single view, I just put the `<script>` at the bottom of the view.  If it affects multiple views, I pull it out into a separate .js and include it at the bottom of the applicable views.

Comment: @charliegriefer, is it ok if you have multiple views with <script> tags (but each script affects only one view), and the script tags are scattered throughout the generated HTML?

Comment: @Daniel T. - I think so, but "ok" is subjective.  The generated HTML is, IMO, really not worth caring much about (as long as it's valid).  You don't maintain the generated code, so to me, it's not really an issue if it looks a bit on the ugly side.  As long as the source is beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just leave that in the view file the way it is.

I am not a big fan of having <script> blocks all over the place though, so I typically will use <cfsavecontent> and <cfhtmlhead> to make sure all these blocks of JS wind up in the <head>

You could do this right in the login.cfm file.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="js">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
            // check that emailField is not empty and is a valid e-mail
            // check that passwordField is not empty
            // if validation fails, add in DOM elements to show error messages
        });
    });
</script>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfhtmlhead text="#js#" />
```